# Error for Fortran Makefile

Tags: makefile, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

My source codes include:

(1) module: *dat_io.f90*, *dimconvert.f90*

(2) main: *elastic.f90*

The following is my Makefile:

```
FC=gfortran
FCFLAGS=-Wall -O3
SRCS = $(wildcard *.f90)
EXES = $(patsubst %.f90,%,$(SRCS))
.f90.o:
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<
SRC_CODE=\
        dat_io.f90\
        dimconvert.f90\
        elastic.f90
OBJ = $(SRC_CODE:%.f90=%.o)
elastic: $(OBJ)
    $(FC) $^ -o $@
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.out *.mod *~ *.dSYM $(EXES)
all: clean elastic
```

When I "make" it, an error pops up:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `dat_io.o', needed by `elastic'.  Stop.
```

So I wonder what's wrong here and how to revise it.